# How to do unit testing in efficient way

Tags: c#, unit-testing

The following is my method

```
User UpdateUser(User user)
{
}
```

Whenever To test this method, I do testing like following.

Nearly I wrote 20 to 30 test cases.

In that, I used following method.

For each testcase I've created User object and give necessary input and also give wrong input to check and finally I'll delete user details which is updated in DB.

for example

```
[TestMethod]
void test1()
{
    try
    {
        // Here will call updateUser and do necessarry check
    }
    finally
    {
        // here I'll delete user details from DB
    }
}

[TestMethod]
void test2()
{
    try
    {
        // Here will call updateUser and do necessarry check
    }
    finally
    {
        // here I'll delete user details from DB
    }
}
```

Is that Correct way of unit testing ?

Because, If i use TestInitialize, that's also called for each test cases.

Am I doing in correct way or is there any other method ?

Comment: You should tag with the programming language and testing framework you're using if you want anyone to be able to answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What C# mocking framework to use?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not a correct way, because this is no longer unit testing, but rather integration tests. Unit testing should NEVER touch the database. but instead use mocks and stubs to imitate the behavior.

If your question is about integration tests, then it's kinda opinion based. It depends on your needs and preferences, as long as it does what you need. I've seen multiple approaches how to handle a situation like this. The most important thing to do is to be consistent. Once you choose one approach, stick with it until the project is finished, so you don't mix multiple programming styles.

Comment: I'm using separate database. I am not using application database..

Comment: @Jeeva, unit tests should test units in isolation. You're still testing the whole database layer too.

Comment: when using a test database its perfectly fine to update the db imo

Comment: Note - unit testing should never touch ANY external source. This is most commonly a database - but also includes web services, the file system, and other running processes.

Comment: @ServéLaurijssen, as long as you don't call it unit testing ;) As others have already mentioned, unit tests should ONLY run in isolation, hence the name "unit testing".

Comment: Testing the business logic of UpdateUser is separate from testing if the database is correctly updated.  Your test methods should do things like check if User is null, check if an incomplete User object is provided, check when bad data is passed, check if an appropriate exception is raised when an error occurs, etc.  It depends on what you need to test, but should be limited to the UpdateUser method.

Comment: @Ninjapig, sure you wanted to posted this as a comment to my answer?

Comment: @Walther I agree with your answer, but wanted to give examples of what kind of things to test for in unit testing.

Comment: Thankx @walther.. but how to do mocks and stubs to imitate the behavior.? is there any example ? Like I should give assurance that the data will update correctly in Db..

Comment: @Ninjapig.. Thankx.. I've done the way you said only.... I've done only for UpdateUser.. And I've inserted data related to check updateUser only .. I didn't use other table while i check UpdateUser method..

Comment: @all, My Problem here is, I want to know Can i create a object for each test case ?

Comment: @JeevaJsb, no offense, but how hard is it to search for a phrase "mock external dependencies c#"? :) This has been asked, answered and documented way too many times already :)

Comment: @walther, Thankx .. you've helped me lot..

Comment: But anyway the UpdateUser method which is written by someone will affect the database ... What I can do here or How can I do ?

Comment: @JeevaJsb Whilst the end result of your code will affect the database, your UpdateUser unit tests should focus on the business logic only.  One approach could be that you could create a class to handle communication with your database, and write unit tests against this new class to test if it is working as expected, but these would not be specific to the UpdateUser method.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

```
[TestMethod]
void test1()
{
  using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
  {
    // Here will call updateUser and do necessarry check

    //just never call scope.Complete() and alle your db changes will be rolled back
  }
}
```

After the test is done (even if it fails by exception) the changes to the DB is rolled back, and you dont need to do the cleanup yourself
In terms of effency im not sure this is a good approch, but it sure is easier :)

Comment: This is how we test our db queries, you can integrate the using() in a base class or aspect. It's no longer really a unit test but more of an integration test.

Comment: @Carra Good idea! And I completly agree with you :) this is integration test. But is still has value in terms of testing the system

Answer (score 0):

If you can change your method to be void the method would be easier to test, and to me it also makes more sense. Right now your method does TWO things (1) updates the user AND (2) return the user. It is always easier to test a method that does ONE thing.

You should not exercise the database in a Unit test - mock it away. Think of it like this; you should be able to run the test with no internet connection and so on. If the code compiles in a context without external systems being accessible your Unit test should be able to execute in the same context.

If you don't have control over the UpdateUser class you should not Unit test it. If your code depends on it you need to mock the UpdateUser so that you can test you classes.

Comment: But anyway the UpdateUser method which is written by someone will affect the database ... What I can do here ?

Comment: You want to have a interface for the database so that you can mock it in your test. You can do this by using dependency injection. If the UpdateUser class is totally out of you control you should not Unit Test it yourself.